# Open new browser window (not tab, not popup) on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

I want to open a url in new window on a button click using javacript.
I have gone through various posts suggesting using params like toolbar,menubar, etc. in window.open() method but all those open a new popup window and not a proper browser window.

I want to open a proper browser window, not a popup window.

Comment: What form a link is opened is a user preference - you cannot force it to be a new tab, if the user doesn't want to. You can only influence whether it goes into a new window which can also be overriden but programmer intent has a bit more sway.

Answer (score 0):

just specify the width and height in the third parameter of `window.open` methid

`window.open("http://yoseftukachinsky.com", "", "width=1920,height=1080");`

if you want to calculate the client screen size, you can do it using:

```
var width = screen.availWidth, height = screen.availHeight;
var myWindow = window.open("http://yoseftukachinsky.com", "", 
"width="+width+",height="+height);
```

Comment: My browser is set to ignore any width/height you might try to specify for a popup, and to open it as a new tab instead of a free-floating window as well.

Answer (score -1):

instade of using javascript you can use target="_blank" in your  in html page.
It will open a new page in your browser with the provided link
example:-

```
<a href="URL" target="_blank"></a>
```